# Better way to listen for events on a Xamarin.Mac object?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm writing a menubar app with pure C# and Xamarin.Mac (no Xcode, so no storyboard), and I find it annoying that when I want to listen for events on an object.

I'm aware I can write something like

```cs
public class MenuDelegate : NSMenuDelegate {
    public class HighlightChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {
        public NSMenuItem? Item { get; set; }
    }
    public event EventHandler<HighlightChangedEventArgs?>? HighlightChanged;
    public override void MenuWillHighlightItem(NSMenu menu, NSMenuItem item) { Opened.Invoke(menu, new HighlightChangedEventArgs() { Item = item }); }
    public event EventHandler? Opened;
    public override void MenuWillOpen(NSMenu menu) { Opened.Invoke(menu, null); }
    public event EventHandler? Closed;
    public override void MenuDidClose(NSMenu menu) { Closed.Invoke(menu,null); }
}


var menuDelagate = new MenuDelegate();
sbIcon.Menu.Delegate = menuDelegate;
menuDelegate.HighlightChanged += (object sender, MenuDelegate.HighlightChangedEventArgs args) => {
    /// stuff
};
```

however this is quite annoying to do, so I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: What specifically is annoying? Having to hook up the event handler, the boiler plate of having to implement NSMenuDelegate? Something else?

Comment: @Cheesebaron: both. Having to create a class, event args class, create the functions to call events, create an object and attach it to the object. Ideally, I'd just be able to attach the event listener to the object.